# UIViewController in a UINavigationController not calling delegate method

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

In my Storyboard, I am using a UINavigationController with a navigation bar to present a view controller. This view controller, ViewController2, is pushed to the stack by tapping a UIBarButtonItem that I placed in the navigation bar. I made this connection in Interface Builder by dragging from the bar button to the ViewController2 scene and selecting "push" for the segue. To return back to the first view controller, I have an `IBAction` that calls the `popViewControllerAnimated` method. I'm using the delegate method to send data back to the first view controller but the string from ViewController2 is not being sent back to ViewController.

How can I pass the text entered in ViewController2 back to the first ViewController using the delegate method?

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,Vc2Delegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *tableArray;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.listTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.listTableView setDataSource:self];

    self.tableArray = @[@"item 1",@"item 2",@"item 3"];

    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [vc2 setDelegate:self];
}

# pragma mark - TableView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.tableArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Delegate Method

- (void)returnFromVc2:(NSString *)userString {
    NSLog(@"delegate text is %@",userString);
}

@end
```

**ViewController2.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol Vc2Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)returnFromVc2:(NSString *)userString;

@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) id <Vc2Delegate> delegate;

@end
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)toPreviousVC:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"user text is: %@",self.textField.text);

    [self.delegate returnFromVc2:self.textField.text];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the delegate to a local variable that won't be the same instance as the one you push.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ....
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [vc2 setDelegate:self];
    ....
}
```

You should also make a habit of checking if your delegate can respond to the message sent.

```
- (IBAction)toPreviousVC:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"user text is: %@",self.textField.text);

    if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector(@selector(returnFromVc2:))] ) {
        [self.delegate returnFromVc2:self.textField.text];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: So how do I set the delegate to the correct instance of the one I push?

Comment: At the place were you push your view controller.

Comment: Ah, so set the delegate in something like `prepareForSegue` instead of `viewDidLoad`?